# Django model not using another model via a foreign key relationship

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a web app that will allow booking onto training sessions in a running club.

I've got my users app and a training_sessions app where coaches can post sessions. They include location, date, the coach taking the session and some details on what the session entails. I now want to add a facility where a logged in user can click on the session and have them booked onto it.

I've a ClubSession model:

```py
class ClubSession(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.location

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('session_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

From it's used in several views to create, edit, delete, view and list all sessions:

```py
class SessionListView(ListView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'club_sessions.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_club_sessions_list'


class SessionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'session_detail.html'
 context_object_name = 'club_session'


class SessionCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'session_new.html'
    fields = ['location', 'coach', 'date', 'details']


class SessionUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'session_edit.html'
    fields = ['location', 'coach', 'date', 'details']


class SessionDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = ClubSession
    template_name = 'session_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

I'm now trying to create a booking model with a foreign key to my user and ClubSessions models. This is what I've got:

```py
class ClubSessionBookings(models.Model):
    athlete = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    club_sessions = models.ForeignKey(ClubSession, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.athlete

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('booking_session_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

I added this view:

```py
class SessionBookingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ClubSessionBookings
    template_name = 'session_booking_new.html'
    fields = ['athlete', 'location', 'coach', 'date', 'details']
    context_object_name = 'session_booking_new'
```

and this url:

```py
path('club_sessions_booking/', SessionBookingCreateView.as_view(), name='session_booking_new')
```

but I see this exception: `Unknown field(s) (coach, date, location, details) specified for ClubSessionBookings`. I guess there's an issue with how my ClubSessionBookings model uses ClubSession as a foreign key. What have I done wrong and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your ClubSessionBooking model has only two fields: `athlete` and `club_sessions`. So you are specifying wrong set of fields in SessionBookingCreateView.

If you just use these two correct fields, it should work.

But in these kind of cases, we like to put a button below the `sessionDetailView` like ‘Register for this Session’. And when a logged in user clicks, the model is created automatically. For that maybe you collect the session Id from button click URL and logged in user from session. Then create the model on the fly instead of using a form.

Comment: Thaks, makes sense. I'll give it a go. Do you have an example of the button you describe?

Comment: Or is there a decent tutorial showing how this could be done?

Comment: Few solutions I have in mind:
1) Quick and dirty: A new URL with custom processing `/register_session/<session_id>`. You get ID from query param and user from request - you create the object on the fly and redirect the user.
2) Using a custom form with just one submit button and hidden session_id field. You put the form below every session. On form submit via POST - object gets created.
3) Using django view mixins: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#using-formmixin-with-detailview

Comment: Also it depends on what kind of frontend you are targeting. Mixins and forms are fine if you are using default Django templates with html views. If you are using Django Rest Framework then don't bother too much. Just set the fields correctly and handle form submissions in the frontend (Android / Vue / React etc.)

Comment: Ah good to know. I don't plan to at the min but may wish to down the line.

Comment: Btw, let me know if the answer solves the initial problem. Or should I look into it again? @runnerpaul